# Невозможна установка canvas nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, canvas

Команда `npm install canvas`
Ошибка:

```js
> canvas@2.5.0 install D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.5.0/canvas-v2.5.0-node-v72-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.5.0 and node@12.2.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
Построение проектов в этом решении по одному. Чтобы включить параллельное построение, добавьте параметр "/m".
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Загрузка компонента Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe" невозможна. Способы решения проблемы: 1) установка .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) установка Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 или 3) указа
ние адреса компонента в системном пути, если компонент установлен в другом месте.  [D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\soft\nodejs\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:257:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "D:\\soft\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\soft\\nodejs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\0000\\Hikka-R\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=D:\\0000\\Hikka-R\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'D:\soft\nodejs\node.exe D:\soft\nodejs\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "D:\\soft\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\0000\\Hikka-R\\node_modules\\canvas\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\0000\Hikka-R\node_modules\canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Пробовал установить sdk framework 2.0 - Не смог, установщик попросту не запускался.
Установить visual studio 2005 я так и не смог.
Собственно, компонент, я не знаю про какой компонент идёт речь. 
Если будет какая-либо информация, прошу сообщить, возможно она натолкнёт меня на путь решения проблемы.

Comment: До сих пор?....

Comment: Параметр "/m" устанавливали?

Comment: Прости за возможно глупый вопрос, но, куда его устанавливать?

Comment: Не знаю... Вы как решите проблему - обязательно опубликуйте здесь решение